# loading images windows azure storage

Tags: php, windows, file, azure, upload

I have this php source that uploads images in windows azure storage

```
<?php
require_once('WindowsAzure/WindowsAzure.php');

use WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder;
use WindowsAzure\Common\ServiceException;

// Create blob REST proxy.
$connectionString='DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=jNbf/qmRENb1HZpSqE/SnkAi8WQyUKPE7AaFgVu1u0AFGPEUsbWW10Y+fZud1OOn7zi18J5VnSC0NadZXU8Bpvsg==';
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connectionString);
$path="files/";
    foreach ($_FILES as $key) {
        if($key['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){
            $name = $key['name'];
            $temp = $key['tmp_name'];
            $size= ($key['size'] / 1000)."Kb";
            move_uploaded_file($temp, $path. $name);
            $content = fopen($path.$name, "r");
            $blob_name = $name;
            try {
                  $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("imgs", $blob_name, $content);
               }
            catch(ServiceException $e){
                    $code = $e->getCode();
                   $error_message = $e->getMessage();
                   echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
            }

            echo "
                <div id='loaded'>
                    <h12><strong>File Name: $nombre</strong></h2><br />
                    <h12><strong>Size: $tamano</strong></h2><br />
                    <hr>
                </div>
                ";
        }else{
            echo $key['error']; 
        }
    }
?>
```

The problem is that I have to save the file in the server hard disk first, and then send it to a container in windows azure, is possible to skip this step and send it directly to windows azure avoiding this line **move_uploaded_file($temp, $path. $name);**?,because I tried doing this:

`$content = $key['tmp_name']`;but does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$content = file_get_contents($key['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: Please explain why this answer would help the user solve their problem.  This may very well solve the issue, but this site serves a dual purpose of serving as an archive for users searching for answers to these problems in the future.  Explanations greatly improve chances this will be helpful to not only the OP, but all future viewers as well.

Answer (score 0):

PHP saves all files loaded from browser in temporary files in some special directory. You receive only a name of this temporary file  in your PHP script, and it is 'tmp_name'.

So, 'tmp_name' is a real file's name and you can skip moving uploaded file and just use this file by reading it's content:

```
$content = file_get_contents($key['tmp_name']);
```